# Lifetime scope with autofac, webforms and ServiceLocator

Tags: asp.net, webforms, autofac, lifetime

In a legacy Asp.NET webforms application, I try to inject some IOC.

I won't enter into details, but for this one, I think ServiceLocator is a good tools for the job.
I know that service locator is an anti-pattern ;o)

According to the documentation https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/wiki/Common-Service-Locator the ServiceLocator configuration goes like this :

```cs
var container = builder.Build();
var csl = new AutofacServiceLocator(container);
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => csl);
```

The problem is that the LoacatorProvider is set with the root container. So, Lifetime management is not active.

I'm thinking of a way to resolve this issue

Because `ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider` takes a delegate as parameter and because this delegate is called on every invocation of `ServiceLocator.Current` why not provide an instance of AutofacServiceLocator per request.

```cs
public class Global : HttpApplication, IContainerProviderAccessor
{
    // Provider that holds the application container.
    static IContainerProvider _containerProvider;

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        _containerProvider = new ContainerProvider(AutoFacBootstrapper.CreateContainer());

        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() =>
        {
            AutofacServiceLocator asl = HttpContext.Current.Items["AutofacServiceLocator"] as AutofacServiceLocator;
            if (asl == null)
            {
                var cpa = (IContainerProviderAccessor)HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance;
                var cp = cpa.ContainerProvider.RequestLifetime;
                asl = new AutofacServiceLocator(cp);

                HttpContext.Current.Items["AutofacServiceLocator"] = asl;
            }
            return asl;
        });
    }

    public IContainerProvider ContainerProvider
    {
        get { return _containerProvider; }
    }
}
```

This code seems to work. `IDisposable` objects are disposed at the end of the request. `InstancePerRequest` configuration is ok.

Is there any issue (performances, memory,...) with this implementation ?

Comment: Are you still using this approach?  We are running into a similar problem.

Comment: In fact, I'm planning to use this approach within a legacy webform app which is not ready yet to welcome pure ioc sugar. I was just asking if it is ok to go this way.

Comment: Guess it is an impossible question ;)  We did something very similar - set locator provider to a func that resolves a service from the root container, which then provides the appropriate service locator based on a child scope.  It is not in production yet but when profiling it seemed to address the memory leak issues we had seen (could not use any out-of-box solutions because we need lifecycle management for WCF and MVC in the same application)

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone else, here's how I implemented this as a request handler.

Here's my Startup.cs:

```c#
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        // ...
        IContainer container = ConfigureAutofac(config);

        // This should be the first middleware added to the IAppBuilder.
        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);

        // Make sure the Autofac lifetime scope is passed to Web API.
        app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);

        app.UseWebApi(config);           

        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new ServiceLocatorHandler());
    }
}
```

I'll show `ServiceLocatorHandler.cs` below.

Here's my `ConfigureAutofac` function for completeness:

```
    private IContainer ConfigureAutofac(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        var assemblies = BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().Cast<Assembly>();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(assemblies.ToArray());

        // Register Web API classes
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);
        builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

        // Register the modules
        // ...

        // Create the container
        var container = builder.Build();

        // Hook up the Web API dependency resolver
        var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        config.DependencyResolver = resolver;

        // ...
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new AutofacServiceLocator(container));

        return container;
    }
```

Lastly, here's the handler:

```
public class ServiceLocatorHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var properties = request.Properties;
        var scope = properties["MS_DependencyScope"];
        AutofacWebApiDependencyScope dependency_scope = scope as AutofacWebApiDependencyScope;
        if (dependency_scope != null && dependency_scope.LifetimeScope != null)
        {
            AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(dependency_scope.LifetimeScope);
            AutofacServiceLocator asl = new AutofacServiceLocator(resolver.Container);
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => asl);
        }
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

In my use case I have a 3rd-party library that uses IoC for resolving `DBContext` implementations via the repository pattern.

This library gets used in other environments using other DI containers, and when using it with the default `AutofacServiceLocator` root setup I'd either see EF caching issues with old data or write fails as new contexts would be created between object add and commit.

Many thanks to OP for helping us solve this.